# MOSS 2007 Server hanging problem - AppDomainUnloadListener.RegisterSelf() & PublishingHttpModule.Init()

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Recently Sharepoint server getting hung now and then; when I see the Logs, I found lots of entries like this,

04/17/2009 10:07:09.51     w3wp.exe (0x11C0)                           0x0CF8    CMS                               Publishing                        8zug    Medium      PublishingHttpModule.Init() calling AppDomainUnloadListener.Register()
04/17/2009 10:07:09.51     w3wp.exe (0x11C0)                           0x0CF8    CMS                               Publishing                        8x0a    High        AppDomainUnloadListener.RegisterSelf() entered lock(this=3183676)

I've no idea what this means, would this be a cause of Serving Hanging problem? Can anyone explain about this error?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Is your farm load balanced?

If so, this issue (referenced only by the errors stated above, so, this may indeed not be your solution if your farm isn't) may be due to an incorrect load balancing configuration.

The issue has come up in other forums when trying to load balance urls on port 80 where the the web applications for those urls are on ports other than 80. Load balanced urls for applications not on port 80 need to include port numbers.

Sharepoint will automatically put the port number onto the end of your load balanced URL, so if you want your load balanced URLs to be all on port 80 you will need to configure Host Headers and setup the web applications on port 80.

Comment: Hi Joshua,
Thanks for your response. The farm is not load-balanced. Do you have any other idea?